# Porque quando o botão é pressionado o texto do primeiro campo não vai para o segundo?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8s">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="text1" type="text"><br>
    <input id="text2" type="text">
    <button id="button" type="button">click</button>

    <script>
        let text1 = document.querySelector("#text1");
        let text2 = document.querySelector("#text2");
        let button = document.querySelector("#button");

        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            text2.textContent = text1.textContent;
        });

    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu estou criando um código em *javascript*   e ele tem o objetivo de pegar o texto do primeiro campo e jogar no segundo campo quando o botão for clicado, mas quando eu clico no botão nada disso acontece e também não retorna nenhum erro no `console` do navegador, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Simples, basicamente não é textContent e sim value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8s">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="text1" type="text"><br>
    <input id="text2" type="text">
    <button id="button" type="button">click</button>

    <script>
        let text1 = document.querySelector("#text1");
        let text2 = document.querySelector("#text2");
        let button = document.querySelector("#button");

         button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            text2.value = text1.value;
        });

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

`textContent` é usado quando o elemento é uma `String`, no caso do `input` como ele vai receber algum valor, ele deve ser manuseado como `value`